# Get Specific Column Value from GridView and save it to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a `GridView` sheet it contains 9 columns

Fr Ex:

> name Address Phnenum Area City State Country fathername Sex

It has 9 columns .

But I want to get only 5 Columns

Fr Ex :

> Name Num FatherName sex Addr

Here in my Case Column names is different in my Project

1.In GridView it has [phnenum] but in my database it has [Num]

2.In GridView it has[Adderess] but in my database it has[addr]

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it's very helpful.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far

Comment: @kumarch1 
 
I tried but all the columns Will stored in database

Comment: show your c# code which u have written to save/retrieve from the db